# Keyboard not working on Chuwi Minibook

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

my keyboard works when trying Kubuntu from the live USB. However, after installation, I cannot type anything at all, not even the login password. I have tried reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-kbd and xserver-xorg-input-all, to no avail.

My Chuwi Minibook runs an Intel M3 and has 16 GB of RAM and a 512 GB SSD. I'm not sure what model the keyboard is (I think it's a highly customised one as it has an unusual layout).

Answer (score 0):

add to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-chuwi.conf

```
blacklist intel_vbtn
```